# Protect routes with React Router v6 and API Call

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJS to protect routes, I am using the most current versions, I even use React Router v6, to protect the routes I send a token with jwt to an API where it confirms that the token is valid and that I can access the other routes . The problem is that the axios call occurs after the check in the javascript code and it never gives me a positive result.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import FormIngreso from "./components/pages/ingreso/FormIngreso";

import Home from "./components/pages/home/Home";

import ProtectedRoutes from "./components/ProtectedRoutes";

export default function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/ingreso" element={<FormIngreso />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

}
```

ProtectedRoutes.jsx

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const useAuth = () => {
  var url = window.$url_api + "/acceso/validar";
  var respuesta = false;

  var token = sessionStorage.getItem("react_session");

  if(token) {
    axios.post(url, {"token" : token})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);  
        var estado = res.data.estado;
        if(estado == 200) {
          console.log("noice");
          respuesta = true;
        }     
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
  }

  return respuesta;
};

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const isAuth = useAuth();
  console.log(isAuth);
  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/ingreso" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

How do I fix my problem?

Comment: hey, maybe I could help to inspect it a little bit more to find whats going on: 
1- what you see in the console logs? 
2- did you have the token in your cookies?
3- are you able to debugging it?

Comment: I think I know what is happening, your excecution is async so probably yo want to await the result of your api and use that to validate isAuth then

Comment: in the console the axios data is visible, but the isAuth variable is loaded before and is shown as false

Comment: thanks for reply.

Comment: usually to have an async call, in react you should use an effect: check this article (is a full explanation)
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/ 
tldr = you have to wrap you api call into a function something like: 
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux');
      setData(result.data);
   };
   fetchData(); //have to call once is defined
 }, []);
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

//now useAuth is not a function anymore is a hook (leaves in the component lifecycle).
const useAuth = () => { 
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      var token = sessionStorage.getItem("react_session");
      var url = window.$url_api + "/acceso/validar";

      if(!token) setIsAuth(false);

      try {
        const res = await axios.post(url, {"token" : token})
        console.log(res);    
        setIsAuth(false);

        if(estado == 200) {
          console.log("noice");
          setIsAuth(true);
        }     
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        setIsAuth(false);
      }
    };          

   };
   fetchData();
 }, []);      

  return isAuth;
};


const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const isAuth = useAuth();

  if (isAuth === null) // waiting..
    return null;

  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/ingreso" />;
};


export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Comment: thanks, it gave me some errors but I solved them using import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

Comment: the only error is

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: isAuth is not a function

Comment: useAuth was the name I fixed

Comment: React Hook "useAuth" is called in function "fetchData" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"

Comment: that is because useAAA is for hooks.
With the mix of useEffect and useState we can create a hook easily. 
I will make this last excersice but try to learn a little bit more about react and react hooks. Will help you to understand why we are doing this.

Comment: done! I've editted the last answer.

The useEffect there can be converted to async too if you want block and wait the execution until the request is done, just changing this :

useEffect(async () => { 
...
await fetchData();
}, []);

Comment: did solve your issue?

Comment: no, I was looking for alternatives and reading guides, it keeps detecting false despite the useAuth(); , I even put a console.log() and the axios works correctly because it receives the token fine but when it reaches the line const isAuth = useAuth(); detects false and returns login even though the token was successfully validated.

Comment: but thanks for the help.

Comment: no worries, just don't give up. The last edition is a hook alternative for the authentication request. At the moment response comes back your component will be updated with the true/false value, so you should see the null while is waiting (maybe put return <p>loading..</p> instead of null to check easily in the UI)

Comment: This loading should be there for a moment then should change to whatever the response is, it won't be detecting false like before, because what you had inside your useAuth function was respuesta variable declared outside the promise to use it inside the POST promise as if were a normal function, it wont happen like that because promises works asynchronously and Javascript engine will enqueue that execution to do after it ends with the current execution, therefore your function was returning false; then ProtecRouter renders the false statement before the promise execution is done.

Comment: continuing with the same case, once false is returned and rendered in the ui, in that moment the JS engine will be free to take care of the enqueued async tasks you sent it before and will try to resolve it, your execution will go into the "then" or "catch" block of the promise, so in this moment you would like to pass your results into the state to force a rerender of the component which now will read the updated value from the state showing your<Outlet> component

Comment: if unrefresh issue, try add async/await to: ............................................................................................................... useEffect(async () => {    .............................................................................................................................................................. await fetchData();